# Ruby on Rails link_to URL and add the id at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to `link_to` a url and would like to add the id at the end. The id is in a global variable @id:

```
<%= link_to "link", "https://www.example.com/sample-#{@id}" %>
```

The above returns this:

```
https://www.example.com/sample-#%3CItem:0x007fe66cf8e850%3E
```

Any idea how I can implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I implement this?

Exactly like you did. Only make sure that `@id` contains an actual id (simple value) and not a complex object `Item`. Or rename it to `@item`.

If you're in a hurry, this is the lazy change:

```
<%= link_to "link", "https://www.example.com/sample-#{@id.id}" %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergio Tulentsev i just had to add .id

Comment: @Theopap No, you have to do the other thing I said.